# sum of rows/columns/total appended in pivot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am using the below pivot_table command to meet my requirement of having the result in the following format

```
active_def = pd.pivot_table(data, index = 'InMonth', columns= 'OutMonth', aggfunc= 'count')['ID']
```

I need a column  towards the end of pivot table having the row totals.  Similarly a row towards the end having the column totals and one cell having sum of all the values in a table. (In simple words, similar to the pivot we usually get in excel).  Is there pythonized way to do it?  I know we can use `data.sum(axis=0/1)` to obtain individually, but, I am looking for a better way to do it.

Thanks!

[image: pivot table results]

Comment: Consider pivot_table's [margins](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#adding-margins).

Answer (score 3):

Use per @Parfait suggestion:

```
active_def = pd.pivot_table(data, index = 'InMonth', columns= 'OutMonth', aggfunc= 'count', margins=True)['ID']
```

OR

You can use this one-liner:

*Data setup*

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.triu(np.random.randint(0,13,(12,12))),
                  columns=np.arange(1,13), 
                  index=np.arange(1,13))
```

*Calculate grand totals for rows, columns, and entire dataframe:*

```
df.append(pd.Series(df.sum(),name='Total'))\
  .assign(Total=df.sum(1))\
  .set_value('Total','Total',df.values.sum())
```

*Output:*

```
       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  Total
1      4   3   6  12   5   9   0  12   1  10   8  10   80.0
2      0   9   8   1   5   1   5  10   7   1   9   2   58.0
3      0   0   2  11   4   0   2   5   4  12   1   7   48.0
4      0   0   0  11   9   2  10   3   0   5   2  10   52.0
5      0   0   0   0   7  12  10  11  12   5   6   0   63.0
6      0   0   0   0   0  12   1   4   1   2  11   0   31.0
7      0   0   0   0   0   0   8  12   8   7   2   1   38.0
8      0   0   0   0   0   0   0  12   7   0   5   9   33.0
9      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  12   4  10   9   35.0
10     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   7   1   11.0
11     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8   2   10.0
12     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5    5.0
Total  4  12  16  35  30  36  36  69  52  49  69  56  464.0
```

Comment: For your last example, I get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'set_value'`

Comment: You are correct, this method is deprecated. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html